# how to convert C++ tesseract-ocr code to Python?

Tags: python, c++, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to convert the C++ version [Result iterator example](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample) in tesseract-ocr doc to Python.

```
  Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract/testing/phototest.tif");
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng");
  api->SetImage(image);
  api->Recognize(0);
  tesseract::ResultIterator* ri = api->GetIterator();
  tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;
  if (ri != 0) {
    do {
      const char* word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);
      float conf = ri->Confidence(level);
      int x1, y1, x2, y2;
      ri->BoundingBox(level, &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2);
      printf("word: '%s';  \tconf: %.2f; BoundingBox: %d,%d,%d,%d;\n",
               word, conf, x1, y1, x2, y2);
      delete[] word;
    } while (ri->Next(level));
  }
```

What I could do till right now is the following :

```
import ctypes
liblept = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('liblept-5.dll')
pix = liblept.pixRead('11.png'.encode()) 
print(pix)

tesseractLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Program Files\tesseract-OCR\libtesseract-4.dll')

tesseractHandle = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPICreate()

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIInit3(tesseractHandle, '.', 'eng')

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPISetImage2(tesseractHandle, pix)
#tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIRecognize(tesseractHandle, tesseractLib.TessMonitorCreate())
```

I cannot convert the  C++ `api->Recognize(0)` to Python(what I have tried is in the last line(commented) of the code, but it is wrong), I am not experienced with C++, so I cannot go on anymore, anyone can help with the conversion ? The APIs:

- From tess4j: http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-3.0/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TessAPI1.html#TessBaseAPIAnalyseLayout-net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITessAPI.TessBaseAPI-
- From the source code: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/420cbac876b06beeee271d9f44ba800d943a8a83/include/tesseract/capi.h

I guess I also have some difficulty on the subsequent conversion , for example , I don't know how to denote `tesseract::RIL_WORD` in Python, so it would be kind to provide me a full version of the conversion , thanks !

I know there is a project named [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) can save me from the conversion , but the problem with the project is they don't provide an uptodate windows Python wheels, which is the main reason for me to do the conversion .

Comment: "C/C++" is not a language. The above is clearly C++, so there's no use mentioning C at all. Also, try not to put things into the title of your question that could as well be placed in the tags. The latter are better suited for effective searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that `api->Recognize()` expects a pointer as first argument. [They mistakenly put a `0` in their example but it should be `nullptr`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/420cbac876b06beeee271d9f44ba800d943a8a83/include/tesseract/baseapi.h#L491). `0` and `nullptr` both have the same value but on 64bits systems they don't have the same size (usually ; I assume on some weird non-x86 systems  this may not be true either).

Their example still works with a C++ compiler because the compiler is aware that the function expects a pointer (64bits) and fix it silently.

In your example, it seems you haven't specified the exact [prototype of `TessBaseAPIRecognize()`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/420cbac876b06beeee271d9f44ba800d943a8a83/include/tesseract/capi.h#L334) to ctypes. So ctypes can't know a pointer (64 bits) is expected by this function. Instead it assumes that this function expects an integer (32 bits) --> it crashes.

My suggestions:

1. [Use `ctypes.c_void_p(None)` instead of 0](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr/blob/49babfa2af93e490bcc132edb5614b5e87a14cf1/src/pyocr/libtesseract/tesseract_raw.py#L481)
2. If you intend to use that in production, [specify to ctypes all the function prototypes](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr/blob/49babfa2af93e490bcc132edb5614b5e87a14cf1/src/pyocr/libtesseract/tesseract_raw.py#L242)
3. Be careful with the examples you look at: Those examples use [Tesseract base API](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/420cbac876b06beeee271d9f44ba800d943a8a83/include/tesseract/baseapi.h) (C++ API) whereas if you want to use libtesseract with Python + ctypes, you have to use [Tesseract C API](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/420cbac876b06beeee271d9f44ba800d943a8a83/include/tesseract/capi.h). Those 2 APIs are very similar but may not be identical.

If you need further help, you can have a look at how things are done in [PyOCR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr/tree/49babfa2af93e490bcc132edb5614b5e87a14cf1/src/pyocr/libtesseract). If you decide to use [PyOCR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr) in your project, just beware that the license of PyOCR is GPLv3+, which implies some restrictions.

Comment: Your description of the differences between `0` and `nullptr` is inaccurate. `0` in this context is not an `int` literal` but a null pointer literal, and as such it has the same size as a `nullptr` object pointer. The compiler does not “fix it silently”.

Comment: Thanks for help ! I use tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIRecognize(tesseractHandle, None) instead, then there is no exceptions, which makes me feel that not specifying function prototypes doesn't matter. Would you mind helping me on another similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188293/question-on-using-ctypes-with-tesserac-ocr-tesspageiteratorboundingbox