# Exception on using ctypes with tesserac-ocr TessPageIteratorBoundingBox

Tags: python, c++, c, tesseract, ctypes

```
import ctypes
import os
os.putenv("PATH", r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR')
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata'

liblept = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('liblept-5.dll')
pix = liblept.pixRead('test.png'.encode())
print(pix)

tesseractLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtesseract-5.dll')

tesseractHandle = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPICreate()

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIInit3(tesseractHandle, '.', 'eng')

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPISetImage2(tesseractHandle, pix)

# text_out = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(tesseractHandle)
# print(ctypes.string_at(text_out))

tessPageIterator = tesseractLib.TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator(tesseractHandle)
iteratorLevel = 3  # RIL_BLOCK,  RIL_PARA,  RIL_TEXTLINE,  RIL_WORD,  RIL_SYMBOL
tesseractLib.TessPageIteratorBoundingBox(tessPageIterator, iteratorLevel, ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0))
```

I got exceptions :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BaiduYunDownload\programming\Python\CtypesOCR.py", line 25, in <module>
    tesseractLib.TessPageIteratorBoundingBox(tessPageIterator, iteratorLevel, ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0), ctypes.c_int(0))
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000018
```

So what's wrong ?
The aim of this program is to get  bounding rectangle of each word. I know projects like  [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) and  [PyOCR](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/pyocr)

P.S. Specifying the required argument types (function prototypes) for the DLL functions doesn't matter here. One could uncoment  the commented lines and  comment the last three lines to test it. I posted the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185269/problem-on-using-ctypes-with-tesserac-ocr-tesspageiteratorboundingbox) before , and it was closed for this reason

Comment: There is no line 25 in your code. Also, why did you tag this with both C++ and C?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Tesseract is built with  C/C++, I guess someone who knows C/C++ might help, so add these tags.

Comment: So what's the *Python* version (and architecture) you're using to run this code?

Comment: @CristiFati Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win7 32bit

Comment: Even if it's on *32bit* I still think it's the same problem as in the closed question. Anyway, I'm not going to propose to close this one.

Comment: @CristiFati I got the same exception even with the function prototypes specified https://pastebin.com/wTEza115

Comment: Could you add the required files from "*.*" or "*eng*"? Cause I can;t get passed the initialization step. Also add the whole program output, not just the exception. And print `tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIInit3(tesseractHandle, '.', 'eng')`'s output.

Comment: @CristiFati see my answer below

Comment: There's no textual description whatsoever. Just a piece of code. People won't do a mental diff between the 2 versions. Also which changes in particular solved the problem? At the end it's still **Undefined Behavior**. tha fact that it works, is pure luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question by myself

```
import ctypes
import os
import io
os.putenv("PATH", r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR')
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata'

liblept = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('liblept-5.dll')
pix = liblept.pixRead(b'test.png')  # 必须encode
print(pix)

tesseractLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libtesseract-5.dll')

tesseractHandle = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPICreate()

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIInit3(tesseractHandle, b'.', b'eng')  # (TessBaseAPI* handle, const char* datapath,const char* language);

# from PIL import Image
# pixmap = Image.open("test.png")
# image = io.BytesIO()
# pixmap.save(image, 'png')  # 没有什么类型，这里就任意指定个吧；For images created by the library itself (via a factory function, or by running a method on an existing image), this attribute is set to None.
# image.seek(0)  # 要回到开始才行，不然后面requests读的时候会从结尾读，读不到数据

tesseractLib.TessBaseAPISetImage2(tesseractHandle, pix)  # pixmap.tobytes("raw", "RGB")
# text_out = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(tesseractHandle)
# print(ctypes.string_at(text_out))
tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIRecognize(tesseractHandle, None)  # 必须有，否则下面会出问题
tessResultIterator = tesseractLib.TessBaseAPIGetIterator(tesseractHandle)  # TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator要用

tessPageIterator = tesseractLib.TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator(tessResultIterator)
wordLevel = 3  # RIL_BLOCK,  RIL_PARA,  RIL_TEXTLINE,  RIL_WORD,  RIL_SYMBOL


left = ctypes.c_int(0)  # 这几个是要用来写入数据的，所以要构造出来 可写；byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not 'int'
top = ctypes.c_int(0)
right = ctypes.c_int(0)
bottom = ctypes.c_int(0)

while True:
    r = tesseractLib.TessPageIteratorBoundingBox(
        tessPageIterator,
        wordLevel,
        ctypes.byref(left),  # byref behaves similar to pointer(obj), but the construction is a lot faster.
        ctypes.byref(top),
        ctypes.byref(right),
        ctypes.byref(bottom)
    )

    text_out = tesseractLib.TessResultIteratorGetUTF8Text(tessPageIterator, wordLevel)
    print(ctypes.string_at(text_out), left.value, top.value, right.value, bottom.value)

    if not tesseractLib.TessPageIteratorNext(tessPageIterator, wordLevel):
        break
```